# cors issue from mobile through laravel application when submitting formdata

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel API and using `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors` plugin. My config/cors.php looks like this

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
```

as a client-side, I am using vue.js (doesn't really matter).

**Question:** From desktop chrome browser, everything works perfectly. No cors issue at all. Then I built it and uploaded on server and from mobile chrome, everything works perfectly except for one page which is responsible to upload formData with 1 image. From desktop, this works great, but not from mobile chrome browser.

What do you think could be a problem?

I used remote devtools. Here is what error i am getting on mobile:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'example.api.com' from origin 'example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

7.7259b24dd9d7819902a2.chunk.js:1 POST api.example.com net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: what is the error message you get on the mobile chrome ? (you can connect your phone to your computer and inspect it's chrome browser with your desktop chrome dev tools)

Comment: i updated it. take a look

Comment: `'example.api.com'` ?!

Comment: Forget about those. I know they are correct. I made a mistake by copying-pasting.

Comment: `barryvdh/laravel-cors` uses `$_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]` to set the ACAO to that domain. maybe from your mobile request it is not set. and `ACAO:*` is no more valid with browsers

Comment: why does this happen only when there's a formData upload? other requests work fine from mobile as well as from desktop.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili that might have nothing to do with the `FormData`, you can try and change the type to json on that same route.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an API for a specific front interface, you can simply set that domain in your `barryvdh/laravel-cors` config. That will avoid mis-detection of the calling domain.

```php
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['example.com'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

You should use a `.env` variable if you have a production release later.

Comment: I don't think how this is gonna solve my issue. wild-card still should work. :)

Comment: As i said, how `barryvdh/laravel-cors` depends en the request containing the calling domain. if it's missing, or in a different header of the request, it wont be able to set it correctly. just try it. you can also `dd($_SERVER)` to check for the request headers.